# Send file pointer to python thread and update file pointer

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-handling

I have a python program with a thread and the thread should write into a file. I will spawn a thread from the main program. Now on new day trigger I will change the file pointer in the main program and I want the thread also to take the new file to write the data to the file.

I have a code which will take global variable and do this task. But is there any other better way of doing this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import threading
import time


filePtr = None

import time

def fileWriteTh():
    global filePtr
    time.sleep(2)
    filePtr.write("from the thrread this should in file 2")


def main():
    global filePtr
    filePtr = open("test1.txt","ab")
    fileThread = threading.Thread(target=fileWriteTh)
    fileThread.start()
    if new_day_trigger:
        filePtr.close()
        filePtr = open("test2.txt","ab")



    fileThread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the new code that is written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import threading
import time

class SendPacket(object):
    fileDesc = None
    def __init__(self, fd):
        super(SendPacket, self).__init__()
        SendPacket.fileDesc = fd

    def printFromInstance(self,var):
        print var
        SendPacket.fileDesc.write(var)
        time.sleep(3)
        print var
        SendPacket.fileDesc.write(var)
    def startabc(self, someVar):
        self.printFromInstance(someVar)

    @classmethod
    def printVar(cls, printStr):
        print printStr
        cls.fileDesc.write(printStr)
    @classmethod
    def changeClsFile(cls, newFd):
        cls.fileDesc = newFd


def main():
    filePtr = open("test1.txt","ab")

    sendPack_inst = SendPacket(filePtr)

    fileThread = threading.Thread(target=sendPack_inst.startabc, args=("test1",))

    fileThread.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    filePtr.close()

    filePtr = open("test2.txt","ab")

    SendPacket.changeClsFile(filePtr)

    fileThread.join()
    filePtr.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's a ridiculous question. The result can only be one. You can't live when you're dead !  If my comment sounds absurd, check where you closed the file.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have changed the code. Does looks good now? @dsgdfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Like this:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import thread
import time

class _fileACT :
    def __init__(self):
        self.trigger = 0
        self.flag = True
        self.msg = ""
        self.files = (open("test1.txt","ab"),open("test2.txt","ab"))
    def run(self,pssrg):
        while self.flag :
            if self.msg != "" :
                self.files[self.trigger].write(self.msg)
                self.msg = ""
    def test(self,pssrg):
        for i in range(20):
            time.sleep(1)
            if i %2 != 0 :
                self.trigger = 0
            elif i %2 != 1:
                self.trigger = 1

            self.msg = "%0.3d test-1,asdasdasd\n"%i
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print "wait..."

        self.flag = False
        for e in self.files : e.close()
        print "can exit !"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileACT = _fileACT()
    thread.start_new_thread(fileACT.run,(None,))
    thread.start_new_thread(fileACT.test,(None,))
```

We have three variables, filename, last opened file name and message. Two files, only False and True will be sufficient (of course you can use index for multiple files). We've written a test function into the class because we don't want our main cycle to freeze. The file selection is done with ' trigger ', but the previous and next file name is not the same, the previous closes.

**The important point in the thread is that the time delay is strictly unavailable!** The time delay is always applied to the trigger. The time delay cannot be placed in the main loop. An instance of access from outside the class is also attached. I hope it helps.

Comment: This is good one but I have used class variables to the new code that I have posted. Is there any problem if I use the class variable and open the file only once in the main method and use the same file in all the other instances of the class?